# How do I make windows similarly to linux require authorization to run executable files

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, anti-virus

I've noticed linux (using ubuntu) is usually requiring you to go to a file's properties and allow the OS to execute it, when the file is unrecognised. Giving this enough thought I realized it is a great way to prevent viruses and accidentally running trojans or anything of that sort, or even trash software you may acquire with time. Is there any way to make windows require you to allow every program to be executed in such a manner?

Trying to do this on windows 10, although knowing how to do it on other windowses wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You can use a group policy to make it possible that a normal user can only launch specific authorized applications.  This is the best way to accomplish your desired goal.  Windows also does what you describe with untrusted files, what sources are untrusted, is determined by your system administrator. [Understand AppLocker rules and enforcement setting inheritance in Group Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/applocker/understand-applocker-rules-and-enforcement-setting-inheritance-in-group-policy)

Comment: [How to configure AppLocker Group Policy to prevent software from running](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5211.how-to-configure-applocker-group-policy-to-prevent-software-from-running.aspx)

Comment: [Using Software Restriction Policies to Protect Against Unauthorized Software](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx)